# How to Share a Specific section of the Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, sharing

guys! I'm trying to create a share button that will share on social platforms a specific section of my Wordpress page. Here's the link: https://blueprintt.intl-l.com/#quote

(It's a quote by P. Drucker). What I need is a code that will share the content from this section. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where specifically would you want to share this to? Email, social media? Any specifics?

Comment: I'd love to share it on FB and Linkedin. I've tried a plugin called PullQuote but it doesn't work. Maybe a plugin that uses a shortcode like [share]Text to share[/share] would be great.

Comment: where is your share method?

Comment: Just activated the plugin. It only shares on Tweeter. I've tried Facebook sharer.php with custom arguments but no luck. Maybe copying the js code from another plugin that haves Linkedin and Facebook will help.